# Difference between batch and transaction in SQL Server in terms of handling errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having a bit of hard time understanding how errors affect the completion of batches and/or transactions.

For instance:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
SELECT 1/0 AS Error;
ROLLBACK;

BEGIN TRAN;
SELECT 1/1 AS NOError;
COMMIT;

GO
```

Should not the second transaction succeed even though the first fails? Are not transactions dealt with on one-by-one basis? And what is the role played by batches here?

I was reading about `SET XACT_ABORT ON` command, and the MSDN says:

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.

If it only fails the containing transaction, why the second transaction is never reached?

Comment: Transactions and errors in SQL Server are confusing. Many edge cases. My advice: Don't manage them in T-SQL. Deal with transactions and errors in the client app (e.g. C#).

Comment: On that error, the entire script stops running so it never gets to the second transaction.

Comment: It does go to the second transaction, unless you specifiy `SET XACT_ABORT ON`. If you seperate the two transaction by a `GO` statement, thus making them two separate batches then the second batch will execute not matter what.

Comment: @usr I disagree that you should handle all transaction and errors in the client app. Often times we do want the error to bubble back up to the client app but error handling in t-sql works quite well, especially for auditing. And please if you are writing web apps don't do your transactions in the web code. You will at some point get hung transactions because the client lost connectivity after you started your transaction.

Comment: @SeanLange good points, especially with connectivity problems. But you have no choice if you want a transaction spanning multiple calls to SQL Server. This is the standard case in the types of apps I work on.

Comment: @usr yes sometimes that is the case. Often times I try to find a way to combine those calls into a single stored procedure call instead of multiples. It is not always easy but you can almost always find a way to do it.

Comment: @JodyT why does not it then show the output of the second transaction? I set XACT_ABORT off. Are errors scoped to all statements in the enclosing batch?

Comment: This is strange, it does show the output for me. Could it be that you are focusing on the "Messages" pane, and not on the "output" one?